# How can i get the base host in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location

I have this in url

`https://192.168.0.10/users/#!/user-profile/20`

$location.host is giving me `192.168.0.10`

I want to only get

`https://192.168.0.10`

How can i get that

Comment: location.host should not give you that. why would it give protocol? You need combination of host plus protocol. Just open console (f12) in chrome and with your webpage open and type `location` see what it shows

Comment: Note that location.origin will not work in IE (until 11). $location is just a wrapper

Comment: @PSL thanks , i got that  from console.

Comment: You said $location.host() is giving you the entire url (as of this edit in the question) then how come host+protocol worked for you? Just wondering.. :)

Comment: @PSL that protocol was given by host , i think it was appened it it. i thought it was part of that. i have edited the question to be more clear to readers now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing:-

```
var protocol = $location.protocol();
var host = $location.host();

var combined = protocol + '://' + host;
```